# Protractor - Drag and Drop Not Working

Tags: typescript, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I am trying to drag and drop one element to another. I can see it pick up the element, and then it moves it off the screen and never drops it where it should.

**Things I have tried**

```
const leftSide =  this.breakdownItems.get(0).getWebElement()
const rightSide = this.groupField.getWebElement()
browser.actions()
.mouseDown(leftSide)
.mouseMove(rightSide)
.mouseUp()
.perform()
browser.sleep(2000)
```

**And**

```
browser.actions()
.dragAndDrop(leftSide, rightSide)
.perform()
browser.sleep(2000)
```

I did find an open defect for Selenium which has not been fixed yet involving drag and drop: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/3604

Has anyone actually gotten this working, because it seems like the standard stuff is not working at all? 
I should also mention that I am only running my tests in Chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use external library: html-dnd: https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-dnd

For me works as charm.

Comment: Thank you so much. This works splendidly. Would upvote this a million times if I could.

Answer (score -1):

The Main reason your script does not run is `dragAndDrop()` method input parameter,
`dragAndDrop` method takes `WebElement` as input, below is the code change you can do.

```
 browser.actions()
.dragAndDrop(leftSide.getWebElement(), rightSide.getWebElement())
.perform()
browser.sleep(2000)
```

Comment: The OP make `leftSide` and `rightSide` WebElements as they did:
`const leftSide =  this.breakdownItems.get(0).getWebElement()
const rightSide = this.groupField.getWebElement()`